# When can I proceed inbound in a hold in lieu of a procedure turn when cleared for the approach?

Tags: faa-regulations, approach, iaps, holding, clearance

Let’s say I am holding on a published hold in lieu of a procedure turn but not yet cleared for the approach. Upon receiving approach clearance (say on the outbound leg of the hold) would I have to cross the fix an additional time before proceeding inbound?

I have attached a picture as an example and a red X where the approach clearance is received.

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused at your question. As ATC, if I issued the approach clearance when you were at the red X, I would expect you to continue on the outbound leg, turn inbound, and cross HXO inbound to the runway. Are you asking if I would expect you to do *another* full hold after receiving the approach clearance? (I would not.)

Comment: You can always request a "victory lap" if you want to do one more turn around the pattern!

Comment: If I were cleared for the approach at the red X, I would, assuming that I was at an appropriate altitude (not too high), immediately begin my turn inbound to HXO and once at HXO begin the approach.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to do a full turn around the holding pattern, you can just cross the IAF and proceed inbound. This is from [the AIM 5-4-9(a)(5)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_4.html):

> The holding pattern maneuver is completed when the aircraft is
> established on the inbound course after executing the appropriate
> entry. If cleared for the approach prior to returning to the holding
> fix, and the aircraft is at the prescribed altitude, additional
> circuits of the holding pattern are not necessary nor expected by ATC.