# If I'm cleared for the approach while established in a hold, can I turn inbound immediately?

Tags: faa-regulations, ifr-navigation, holding, cfi

If you are established in holding and on an outbound leg (say you are 30 sec outbound on a 1 min or 3.5nm on a 7nm leg) and you are subsequently “cleared approach,” are you allowed to immediately turn inbound to commence the approach or are you required to continue fly outbound according to the published pattern? Is there an FAA reference?

Note: not HILOPT

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! This seems very similar to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/86681/62); does it help?

Comment: I think this question is different. As I read them, this q asks whether you can truncate a hold when given an approach clearance, the other q asks if one extra "lap" is required after clearance.

Comment: Functionally identical questions though, and with the same answer:  When cleared for an approach you are expected to commence the approach with no undue delay.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, unless ATC instructions/charted instructions specify something to the contrary, you can immediately turn inbound for the holding fix, as long as you stay within the protected area till you leave the holding fix for the approach.